# Fetching all user by retrofit in RecyclerView

Tags: android, json, android-recyclerview, retrofit2

My recyclerView showing only first user data.but when i check allusers data in my  http://localhost/MyApi/public/allusers  , it showing 6 user data as a JSON format

**This is my JSON Image**
[Json image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zAHxL.png)

**My SingleTon class**

```
public class RetofitClient_SingleTone {

private static final String BASE_URL = "http://192.168.0.100/MyApi/public/";
private static RetofitClient_SingleTone mInstance;
private Retrofit retrofit;

public RetofitClient_SingleTone() {
    retrofit=new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
}
public static synchronized  RetofitClient_SingleTone getInstance(){
    if (mInstance==null){
        mInstance = new RetofitClient_SingleTone();
    }
    return mInstance;
}

public Api getApi(){
    return retrofit.create(Api.class);
 }
}
```

**My Api.class**

```
 public interface Api {
   @GET("allusers")
  Call<UsersResponse> getUsers();
 }
```

**2 Model Class**

**1. My UserResponse.class**

```
 public class UsersResponse {
  @SerializedName("error")
  @Expose
  private Boolean error;
  @SerializedName("users")
  @Expose
  private List<User> users = null;

  public UsersResponse(boolean error, List<User> users) {
     this.error = error;
     this.users = users;
  }

  public boolean isError() {
     return error;
 }

 public List<User> getUsers() {
     return users;
  }
 }
```

**2. My User.class**

```
public class User {
 @SerializedName("id")
 @Expose
 private Integer id;
 @SerializedName("email")
 @Expose
 private String email;
 @SerializedName("name")
 @Expose
 private String name;
 @SerializedName("school")
 @Expose
 private String school;

 public User(int id, String email, String name, String school) {
    this.id = id;
    this.email = email;
    this.name = name;
    this.school = school;
 }

 public int getId() {
    return id;
 }

 public String getEmail() {
    return email;
 }

 public String getName() {
    return name;
 }

 public String getSchool() {
    return school;
  }
 }
```

**My Adapter Class Users_Adapter .class**

```
public class Users_Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Users_Adapter.UserViewHolder> {

private Context context;
private List<User> userList;

public Users_Adapter(Context context, List<User> userList) {
    this.context = context;
    this.userList = userList;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public UserViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.recyler_view_users, parent, false);



    return new UserViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull UserViewHolder holder, int position) {

    User user = userList.get(position);
    Log.e("Name -  - - -", "onBindViewHolder: "+user.getName() );
    holder.name_TV.setText(user.getName());
    holder.email_TV.setText(user.getEmail());
    holder.school_TV.setText(user.getSchool());
}
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return userList.size();
}
//create class that extend ViewHolder class
public class UserViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView name_TV;
    TextView email_TV;
    TextView school_TV;

    public UserViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        name_TV = itemView.findViewById(R.id.texview_name);
        email_TV = itemView.findViewById(R.id.texview_Email);
        school_TV = itemView.findViewById(R.id.texview_school);
     }
  }
 }
```

**MY Fragment Class UsersFragment.class**

```
public class UsersFragment extends Fragment{

RecyclerView recyclerView;
private Users_Adapter adapter;
private List<User> userList;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.users_fragment,container,false);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);


    recyclerView=view.findViewById(R.id.recylerView_id);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

    Call<UsersResponse> call= RetofitClient_SingleTone.getInstance().getApi().getUsers();

    call.enqueue(new Callback<UsersResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<UsersResponse> call, Response<UsersResponse> response) {

            userList = response.body().getUsers();
            adapter=new Users_Adapter(getActivity(),userList);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<UsersResponse> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
}
}
```

I Want to show all user in recyclerView But it Showing only first user

**app screenshort**

[image]

Comment: Please do not use "Solved" in title. If you've solved your problem, please post an self answer here.

Comment: @Shashanth, This code is Working fine. I find out my mistake after posting here. My mistake was **recyler_view_users.xml (custom XML Row user)**.  The problem was the layout height. I use their match_parent  that's why my other user below the screen. when i scrolling, i saw the other user.that's my mistake. thanks for your comment.